# Does using WHERE col_name LIKE statement increase performance?

Tags: sql

I have always thought a WHERE statement was good for performance and other answers here tend agree, but looking at the following I am wondering if the WHERE statement helps.

```
UPDATE prod_table SET desc = REPLACE(desc, 'old text', 'new text') WHERE desc LIKE '%old text%'
```

Basically changing a portion of a product description in around 300 items out of around 30000. Since the existing description only exists where it needs to be changed, logically the WHERE statement is unnecessary. I have no idea of the inner workings of SQL so unsure if the LIKE search would more quickly identify the records that require updating or if running REPLACE on everything would yield similar performance.

In this instance it is not important - I am really seeking some clarification on the question if a logically unnecessary WHERE statement is actually useful for performance or other good practice reasons.

Comment: a WHERE clause is only "good for performance" if it leverages an index.  a basic WHERE without an index gives no benefit to performance and could actually be a drag on performance, such as in your case where it has to scan every string for a pattern, and doubly so when it has to search twice (once to filter, again to replace)

Comment: you should be able to get the explain plan for each version of your query and compare them

Comment: A predicate in the *where* clause is only necessary or beneficial if it enables the query optimizer to reduce the rows it has to either read or update; a lot of that is down to the specific query, the indexes available and the specific query engine - different database platforms employ various advanced query processing and optimisations tecniques; On your example, if the predicate does not impact the result of the query, being an *unsargable* predicate means it is likely of no benefit since a scan of all rows is going to be required regardless;

Comment: ...even if it were beneficial, a tipping point exists where, because you are updating the table, at some point using an index and then a lookup to modify the row in the base table becomes more costly than simply directly scanning and updating the base table.

Comment: its depends on cardinality (the number of rows estimated by the optimizer) for the qualifiyed predicate (the search clause). If there is fews rows upon a big table, yes this WHERE will act faster. I other cases it will not, but probably never more rather than without...

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the comments, I was concerned with the idea that I was searching twice once to filter and once to replace. The idea of sargability is new to me and very useful - have found some methods of avoiding LIKE '%...%' that may work better. Also the concept of cardinality is useful, as is the explain plan - will be looking into these a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the WHERE clause will be faster because the number of update operations is less, and the difference shouldn't be that great, but it will vary from database to database.

Both ways read every row from disk and perform a similar operation, either finding and replacing text, or just finding - there's not much difference there.

Depending on the database, the cost of a no-op update varies and that will be the source of the difference in performance.